# What does this exercise want me to solve?

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an exercise in "Complex analysis -silverman"

> Let $y=y_0$ be a line parallel to the $x$-axis in the complex plane.
>
> What is the image of it under Log ($z^2$)? (Principal value)

Simple arithmetic shows that a map $w=z^2$ takes the line to a parabola $u=(\frac{v}{y_0})^2 - {y_0}^2$.

So i have to get the image of this parabola under Log function.

Is it possible to designate the exact equation for the image with elementary functions?

For what this exercise is intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z=x+iy_0$ then $\mathrm{Log}(z^2)=u+iv$ with $-\pi\lt v\leqslant\pi$ and
$$
x^2-y_0^2+2\mathrm ixy_0=z^2=\mathrm e^u\cdot(\cos v+\mathrm i\sin v),
$$
thus, 
$$\mathrm e^u=x^2+y_0^2,\qquad\mathrm e^u\cos v=x^2-y_0^2,\qquad\mathrm e^u\sin v=2xy_0.
$$
One sees that 
$$
\mathrm e^u\cos v=\mathrm e^u-2y_0^2,
$$
that is,
$$
\mathrm e^u\sin^2(v/2)=y_0^2.
$$
This proves that the image of the line $\{z\in\mathbb C\mid\Im z=y_0\}$ is included in the curve $C(y_0^2)$ where, for every $t\gt0$,
$$C(t)=\{(u,v)\in\mathbb R^2\mid-\pi\lt v\leqslant\pi,\mathrm e^u\sin^2(v/2)=t\}.$$
A careful examination of the images of $x+\mathrm iy_0$ when $x$ varies, first from $-\infty$ to $0$, $0$ excluded, then from $0$ to $+\infty$, $0$ included, shows that the image of the line is the full set $C(y_0^2)$.

Comment: Why does $\sin(v/2)$ have the sign of $y_0$?

Comment: I was mistaken. See Edit.